# Cookie parameter value problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I want to use cookie in my project. But now i m using session. And i have some session parameters in .aspx pages.. for example:

```
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="refKlinik_id" SessionField="refKlinik_id" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

Now i want to use Cookie Paramter like that:

```
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:CookieParameter Name="refKlinik_id" CookieName="refKlinik_id"
 </SelectParameters>
```

but cookie's value is like that: sauidpU655614411262762102024i1600369917542431520431414503529630051999*CoreID683251601618012627621046&c

but i need an integer value like 24.

How can i convert cookie's value to int32

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it the correct way to assign a Cookie to a DataSource Parameter, so there must be something wrong with your code to store the cookie in the first place.

To store the Cookie you should be doing something like this:

```
HttpCookie myCookie1 = new HttpCookie("refKlinik_id");
myCookie1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(valueToBeAdded);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie1);
```